# What proof will be sufficient for the existence of God?

Tags: theology

A simple question.

What proof will be sufficient for the existence of God? (where God is someone who is all capable ,all knowing , all  present)

Comment: See very very similar post : [what-can-suffice-as-a-scientific-proof-for-god](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6211/what-can-suffice-as-a-scientific-proof-for-god-to-what-domain-can-such-a-proof).

Comment: None, this is why it takes faith. Many [arguments for God's existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existence_of_God#Arguments_for_the_existence_of_God) have been offered over the centuries, none of them is considered conclusive.

Comment: Any such proof would have to start with a coherent definition. That in itself is a subject worthy of many books.

Answer (score 3):

Scientific proof would be easy to come by. Suppose there is a creature that, when prompted, will answer any question and produce/vanish/alter any item in any way. That would (after some months of testing) quite certainly be accepted as a God by most scientists ('a' because existence of one does not preclude existence of another). On the other hand, being all powerful, a God could easily provide everyone with whatever that person views as incontrovertible proof, or even memory of having been provided such.

Comment: As a corollary, if such a God exists, it seems She doesn't want to be known by all of us.

Comment: This doesn't seem to cover the "all capable ,all knowing , all present" requirement.  We can't test for infinite knowledge, because we can't verify infinite knowledge.  We could find that the purported God can create anything we can think to ask for, but that doesn't mean it can create absolutely anything.

Comment: @DavidThornley ... just as we cannot prove that any living organism, apart from the individuals we studied, is composed from cells - science will often make sweeping claims, so if Mr. God moves 50 randomly chosen (by the experimenter) moons in the solar system along chosennon-continuous paths while altering size, color, and elemental composition, science would accept His moon-powers as limitless. It's the old joke: 'Oh, look there are black sheep here!' 'Well, actually at least one black sheep' 'Well actually at least one sheep that's currently black on the side we see.' 'Well, actually...

Answer (score 0):

Even if a god existed, even if he willingly interacted with humans on a regular basis, it would still have been very hard and extremely unlikely to receive a scientific proof of his divine qualities: omnipotence, omniscience and ubiquity. Although such a god could demonstrate his powers by performing miracles, we still would have no way of validating that he can do *anything*, as well as *anywhere* in the universe.

I see only one way how a god could prove these qualities: by granting humans omniscience. If humans could become all-knowing, they could gain understanding of the god's powers and see how they work and why. An omniscient human would be able to validate whether that god is actually omnipotent, omniscient and ubiquitous.

Answer (score -2):

Have you ever seen a better creation than this world and the galaxy including the stars and other planets? You should believe in another world after dying.  There you will see God.

Comment: It helps to add references in an answer pointing the reader to sources where they can get more information. I will try to edit your answer for grammar, but you may roll back what I have done if you find it inappropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this answer is saying. What does the first sentence mean by "better", how does it relate to the following two?

Comment: Pretty nonsensical answer.

Comment: And I've never seen a worse creation than this world etc. etc.